# Range isn't matching up with the list

Tags: python

I'm still new to coding and I came across this example. How come the range is 5 and not 6?

```
NameList=["Olivia", "Madison", "Mia", "Emily", "Charlotte", "Amelia"]

NoMoreSwap=False

while NoMoreSwap==False:
    NoMoreSwap=True
    for Index in range(5):
        if NameList[Index]>NameList[Index+1]:
            Temp=NameList[Index]
            NameList[Index]=NameList[Index+1]
            NameList[Index+1]=Temp
            NoMoreSwap=False


print("The name list is: ", NameList)
```

Comment: To avoid `list index out of range` exception in `NameList[Index + 1]`.

Comment: Use tools like [`Python Tutor`](https://shorturl.at/jpuy8) to visualise basic problems to understand or debug.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are working with `Index` index and `Index + 1` index you would get out of range since last index `5+1 (for Index in range(6))` is the last one in the loop you asked about.

Your list has 6 values -> `len(list)==6` but `list[5]` is your last index.